# ASP.NET MVC: PathInfo Limit?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, max, pathinfo

One of the limitations of ASP.NET 2.0 was that PathInfo was limited to 255 characters. Is that limit a problem in ASP.NET MVC urls, or is there any sort of length limit with ASP.NET MVC routing urls?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, the limit is imposed by the browser, not ASP.NET. For example,

For IE, it's 2,083 characters.

The 255 character limit is a warning by the RFC 2068 which states:
Servers should be cautious about depending on URI lengths above 255 bytes, because some older client or proxy implementations may not properly support these lengths.

Also, with ASP.NET MVC, the PathInfo length will be 0, so any limit on PathInfo size would not apply. I just tried it out and sure enough, I was able to make an MVC request with 2083 characters in IE7.